# script.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm just learning javascript and I'm having some trouble. I wanted to generate a photo using a button click linked to the JS function... And I don't see what's wrong with my code, and it gives the above error when I click on the generate button. I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null error messages every time it tries to generate the picture.

Code is given below

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\minur\Desktop\JavaScript CrashCourse\Challenge 1\css\style.css">
    <title>Javascript on Steroids</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container-1">

        <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days<h2>

        <div class = "flex-box-container-1">

             <div> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">reset</button> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Container-2">
        <h2>Challenge 2: Cat Generator</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()"> Generate Cat</button>

        <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-Cat-Gen">

        </div>
    </div>


    <script src = 'C:\Users\minur\Desktop\JavaScript CrashCourse\Challenge 1\js\script.js'></Script> 
</body>
</html>

//--------------js functions------------------------------

function ageInDays(){
     var birthYear = prompt("What year were you born friend...?");
     var ageInDayss = (2020 - birthYear)*365;
     var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
     var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are '+ ageInDayss + ' days old');
        h1.setAttribute('id','ageInDays');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
}

function reset(){
    document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
}


function generateCat(){
    var image = document.getElementById('img');
    var sm = document.getElementById('flex-Cat-Gen');
    image.src = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/13CoXDiaCcCoyk/giphy.gif';
    sm.appendChild(image);

}
```

Comment: js cant find `id="img"` if its not on the dom

Comment: also learn about relative paths, `C:\Users\minur\Desktop\JavaScript CrashCourse` is doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is no img element with **id image**.

Now inside generate cat function ,create element dynamically same as you created in ageInDays function.

```js
function ageInDays(){
     var birthYear = prompt("What year were you born friend...?");
     var ageInDayss = (2020 - birthYear)*365;
     var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
     var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You are '+ ageInDayss + ' days old');
        h1.setAttribute('id','ageInDays');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);
}

function reset(){
    document.getElementById('ageInDays').remove();
}


function generateCat(){
    if(document.getElementById('cat') === null){
    let image = document.createElement('img');
    image.id="cat";
    let sm = document.getElementById('flex-Cat-Gen');
    image.src = 'https://media.giphy.com/media/13CoXDiaCcCoyk/giphy.gif';
    sm.appendChild(image);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\minur\Desktop\JavaScript CrashCourse\Challenge 1\css\style.css">
    <title>Javascript on Steroids</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "container-1">

        <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days<h2>

        <div class = "flex-box-container-1">

             <div> 
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">reset</button> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div id="flex-box-result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="Container-2">
        <h2>Challenge 2: Cat Generator</h2>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="cat-generator" onclick="generateCat()"> Generate Cat</button>

        <div class="flex-box-container-2" id="flex-Cat-Gen">

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```